# Pure Javascript library for charts displaying

Tags: javascript, charts

I am looking for a pure Javascript chart library to embed in my Javascript client, as I need to display multiple variables in one single chart.

The library will be possibily embedded in a future product with commercial purposes, so the
release license should fit this requirement...

I've been using ExtJS so far, but it isn't helping.

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I want the community to give me suggestions, not Google!!! Otherwise, I wouldn't have asked...

Answer (score 2):

Try using http://highcharts.com/